# jquery stops tag from showing in webpage

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code (img): http://postimg.org/image/qlmuutwg5/

But the page title is just showing as the URL and not the title inside the tag.

When i remove:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

from my code, the title tag shows fine. i have tried using a different version of JQuery but it still causes the same issue.

It is causing this issue in Firefox, IE, Chrome and Safari

Comment: Can you paste your code here in question itself instead of posting image on external URL?

Comment: It is hard to say what section of the javascript is causing the problem. First, place all meta tags at the top of the document, then, the title, just to be sure it has nothing to do with it. Then, start removing the scripts one by one from the bottom of the list of scripts (not the top), until you find code segment that is causing the problem. Unfortunately, this is debugging that only you can perform.

Comment: ok it seems to be this causing the issue: `<script src="<?php echo $Settings_PathName; ?>/includes/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` however i have also removed all code from this file so it is empty however its still causing the  same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the title tag after you've loaded the viewport,

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title></title>
```